# What is the eigenvalue of the Casimir element of $su(n)$ in the defining representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am currently in the process of learning some representation theory, and I am trying to derive a form for the Casimir element $C_n$ of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ given some fixed basis. To verify if my derivation is correct, I want to see if, in the defining representation $\pi_n$ of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ as $n \times n$ traceless, anti-Hermitian matrices, my form of the Casimir is the correct multiple of the $n \times n$ identity matrix:

$$\pi_n(C_n) = \lambda_n I_n.$$

My question is: what is $\lambda_n$ as a function of $n$? Also, is there a way to determine $\lambda_n$ that doesn't involve explicitly calculating the matrix $\pi_n(C_n)$?

I've managed to verify that $\lambda_2 = 3/4$ and $\lambda_3 = 4/3$ by calculating the Casimir operator explicitly.